# Overriding MUI Chip deleteIcon color

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I am trying to give custom color to `deleteIcon` of `Chip` component (MUI v5). As I can see, my styles are overridden by `.css-inlzrk-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiChip-root .MuiChip-deleteIcon` , but I could not override it. I don't want to give inline styles (eg. `<Cancel style={{color: 'blue'}} />`).

[image]

[image]

```js
import * as React from "react";
import Chip from "@mui/material/Chip";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";

import Cancel from "@mui/icons-material/Cancel";

export default function DeleteableChips() {
  const classes = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    icon: {
      color: "blue"
    }
  }))();

  const handleDelete = () => {
    console.info("You clicked the delete icon.");
  };

  return (
    <Stack direction="row" spacing={1}>
      <Chip
        className={{ deleteIcon: classes.deleteIcon }}
        label="Deletable"
        onDelete={handleDelete}
        deleteIcon={<Cancel className={classes.icon} />}
      />
      <Cancel className={classes.icon} />
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

CodeSandbox :
https://codesandbox.io/s/deleteablechips-material-demo-forked-d6jq5?file=/demo.js

Comment: the demo is currently broken (*`Could not find dependency: '@mui/styles'`*). can you try and fix it so it's easier to reproduce? thanx!

Comment: i guess i forgot to save package.json. can i give a try again?

Comment: cool, it's working now

Comment: Icon is not blue inside Chip... Or is it working for you? Are both cancel icons are blue 
 on your browser?

Comment: i see. nevermind, i didn't understand the issue fully it seems

Comment: got it now - see my answer :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should not use `makeStyles` or anything from the `@mui/styles` package in v5. From the [docs](https://mui.com/styles/basics/#main-content):

> `@mui/styles` is the legacy styling solution for MUI. It is deprecated in v5. It depends on JSS as a styling solution, which is not used in the `@mui/material` anymore. If you don't want to have both emotion & JSS in your bundle, please refer to the `@mui/system` documentation which is the recommended alternative.

The alternatives are `sx` prop/`styled()`. Below are 2 examples of them:

##### `sx` prop

```
<Chip
  sx={{
    '& .MuiChip-deleteIcon': {
      color: 'red',
    },
  }}
  label="Deletable"
  onDelete={() => {}}
/>
```

##### `styled()`

```
const options = {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'deleteIconColor',
};
const StyledChip = styled(
  Chip,
  options,
)(({ deleteIconColor }) => ({
  '& .MuiChip-deleteIcon': {
    color: deleteIconColor,
  },
}));
```

```
<StyledChip
  label="Deletable"
  onDelete={() => {}}
  deleteIconColor="orange"
/>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Thanks! I was mid of upgrading hustle from v4 to v5. Really good insight from docs.

Comment: that's a great answer! I'm upgrading to v5 now and I couldn't understand well how to override the classes with styled!

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this.

```
const classes = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    icon: {
      "&.MuiChip-deleteIcon": {
        color: "blue"
      }
    }
}))();
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/deleteablechips-material-demo-forked-9qllg?file=/demo.js:251-380) for a live working example of this usage.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**:You can override classes `deleteIcon`

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    deleteIcon: {
      color: "red"
    }
  })
);
```

```
      <Chip
        classes={{ deleteIcon: classes.deleteIcon }}
        label="Deletable"
        onDelete={handleDelete}
      />
```

Chech this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-x2dx7?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: why? it makes no difference with `className`: https://codesandbox.io/s/deleteablechips-material-demo-forked-2xhri?file=/demo.js:523-541

Comment: @EliranMalka doesnt show to me, are you referring to the icon inside the chip

Comment: It did not work for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/deleteablechips-material-demo-forked-czzjs?file=/demo.js Am i missing something?

Comment: @Kerematam I have updated my example, maybe it will be useful